# Prove about direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove if $W=W_1+\cdots+W_k$ then $\dim(W)=\dim(W_1)+\cdots+\dim(W_k)$
I'm trying to prove this but is a little complicated for me. Can someone help me?

Comment: It can be shown that any number of eigenvectors associated with distinct eigenvalues are necessarily linearly independent

Comment: Yes, sorry i go to correct that. @DonAntonio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that for $\;1\le i\neq j\le n\;$ , we have

$$x\in\ker (\lambda_iI-T)\cap\ker(\lambda_jI-T)\implies Tx=\lambda_ix=\lambda_jx$$

and since $\;\lambda_i\neq\lambda_j\;$ , we get that $\;x=0\;$ .

Generalizing over the above, you get

$$\;\sum_{i=1}^k W_i=\bigoplus_{i=1}^k W_i = \text{  direct sum}\;$$

Comment: @Bvss12 The danger here for you is to assume that, for direct sum, it is enough to prove $W_i\cap W_j=\{0\}$ for all pairs $1\le i,j\le n, i\ne j$. It is not, so the generalisation is a bit more complicated.

Comment: @user8734617 ...and that's why I wrote "generalizing over the above". The OP must prove that $$\forall\,i=1,2,...,k\;,\;\;W_i\cap\sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^kW_i=0\;$$ ... But also this is pretty simple

Comment: Why $\lambda_i \not = \lambda_j$? thanks for you answer. is very clear

Comment: @Bvss12 Did you mean $\;\lambda_i\neq \lambda_j\;$ ? Because **you** wrote so...and it must be so, of course.

Comment: By hypothesis we know $W=W_1+...+W_k$ then for prove $\;\sum_{i=1}^k W_i=\bigoplus_{i=1}^k W_i = \text{  direct sum}\;$ we need prove $W_1\cap ...\cap W_k =\{0\}$ follow your steps, i take $x\in W_1\cap...\cap W_k\implies T(x)=x\lambda_1 =x\lambda_2 =...=x\lambda_k $ i was thinking why $\lambda_1\not =...\not = \lambda_k$

Comment: Please do not what I wrote in my first comment above that must be proved. It is *not* what you wrote.

Comment: I'm trying to generalize your result.

Comment: @Bvss12 I know but it is done as written in my first **comment** above, not the way you proposed.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks. I go to trying prove this $\forall\,i=1,2,...,k\;,\;\;W_i\cap\sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^kW_i=0\$. Thanks for take the time for answer me.